# openCV : imread return empty matrix and Stitcher.stitch report error

Tags: c++, opencv

Environments: Windows 7 x64、Visual Studio 2013、openCV 2.4.9

I am new to openCV and C++. Just have configured the environment of opencv, then I copy some programs from Internet for Testing, as the result,one of them go right but some report error.

1.First problem:

I can only post 2 link so I make two image into one.

The above program run normally and the under one get error, we can see the “imread()” return empty matrix. And I know it report error at the line: "imshow()" by debugging.

if I change the under codes: replace "imread" with "cvLoadImage", it can display image, but the label of window is still unidentifiable chinese code.

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include<iostream>  
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>  
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("G:\\demo.png");

    cvNamedWindow("图像显示窗口");
    cvShowImage("图像显示窗口", img);
    cvWaitKey(0); 
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvDestroyWindow("图像显示窗口");
    return 0;


    waitKey(6000);
}
```

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include<iostream>  
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>  
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  


using namespace cv;


int main()
{
    // 读入一张图片（游戏原画）  
    Mat img = imread("G:\\demo.png");
    // 创建一个名为 "游戏原画"窗口  
    namedWindow("游戏原画");
    // 在窗口中显示游戏原画  
    imshow("游戏原画", img);
    // 等待6000 ms后窗口自动关闭  
    waitKey(6000);
}
```

[image]

2. Seccond problem:

I replace the imread() with cvLoadImage(), in the watch img has data, and the line "stitcher.estimateTransform()" is added myself, then at this line it reports the same error af next line: "stitcher.stitch()".

I think whether cvLoadImage can not use together with Mat type or Stitcher, but imread will return empty matrix.

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

bool try_use_gpu = false;
vector<Mat> imgs;
string result_name = "result.jpg";

//void printUsage();
//int parseCmdArgs(int argc, char** argv);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Mat img = cvLoadImage("12.JPG");
    imgs.push_back(img);
    img = cvLoadImage("22.JPG");
    imgs.push_back(img);

    Mat pano;
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(try_use_gpu);
    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.estimateTransform(imgs);
    status = stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano);

    if (status != Stitcher::OK)
    {
        cout << "Can't stitch images, error code = " << int(status) << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    imwrite(result_name, pano);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Whether there have something wrong with the codes or configuration? I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Add your code as text, not as image

Comment: This is my first time to touch stackoverflow, so there have something wrong with formats, thanks for pointing it for me. And I have checked and modified my post.

Comment: @Whitiny For the `imread`, at times I had issues when not passing the full path to the image. Try doing that.

Comment: @eshirima I have tried the full path, but still return empty matrix.

Comment: Try to add the library #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"